# Bot Framework Providing a link to open conversation with a separate person/bot

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I would like my chatbot to be able to directly open a chat with another person/bot. This could be for if something isn't covered by the bot and they need to directly talk to a person, or if another bot has the functionality that they need. This functionality already exists in the `Who` app on Teams:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZGHw.png

If I click the Highlighted Message bubble icon, it would directly open a chat here with Jeff. I don't know how to implement this functionality for my bot but I can see that it exists already in Teams, does anyone have a suggestion for how this was built or where I can start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is deep linking to a chat feature. Please have a look at documentation on how to [implement deeplink to a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat).

Example: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>,...&topicName=<chat name>&message=<precanned text>`

Please let us know if you need more details or any queries.